# iterating through a dataframe and doing an operation on every element

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe df

```
          Red    Green   Yellow  Purple
Basket1    1      2        0       10
Basket2    4      5        0       0
Basket3    9      10       11      12
```

I want to iterate through this dataframe and divide each element by the total in each column. Example the first element would be 1/14. I know many pieces of code but unable to put it together. For ietrating I use

```
for idx, row in df.iterrows:
```

and for the column mean I use df.sum(axis=0)
Please help me out with the intermediate code.

Comment: `df / df.sum()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This ought to do the trick:

```
>>> df/df.sum()
              Red     Green  Yellow    Purple
Basket1  0.071429  0.117647     0.0  0.454545
Basket2  0.285714  0.294118     0.0  0.000000
Basket3  0.642857  0.588235     1.0  0.545455
```

As for your serial "iterating through a dataframe and doing an operation on every element" approach, just know that, while a `for` loop is sometimes the easiest and most-intuitive way to get the job done, `pandas` is built for vectorization (i.e. doing things *really* quickly). When you have lots of data, finding a way to use built-in `pandas` is often the best tool for the job.